# Adding a Canon PIXMA MX860 wireless printer?

Tags: printing, canon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a Canon Pixma MX860 network printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75887/how-do-i-add-a-canon-pixma-mx860-network-printer)

Were do I go or click on to bring up system so I can follow the steps to add a wireless printer. A Canon PIXMA MX860 ?

Comment: Did you manage to connect it? I have the same problem. Set it up as it is described in CUPS documentation but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

System->Administration->Printing

Click the "Add" button in the toolbar; it will guide you through the rest.

Comment: -1 For Canon printers you have to install a driver from Canon website.