# How to install Canon pixma mx300 printer with ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: printing

I have 14.04 lts. How do I setup my canon pixma mx300 printer?

Comment: Did you try to use the printer setting and see an error? Or is it about finding the printer settings?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions here may get you started, or at least point you in the right direction:

[Adding Canon Pixma MX860 to Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504436/adding-canon-pixma-mx860-to-ubuntu-14-04/504559#504559)